# Merging .root files causing copies of the merged file

Tags: macros, root-framework

I wrote a macro to loop through and merge several .root files of data collected hourly, in an attempt to take several hourly files and turn it into daily files instead. For some reason it is creating several copies of it and all the information within it. For example, when I try to look into the tree containing the data from all the trees, it says "clusters_Tree; 61".

I am attaching my macro, any idea how I could fix this?

```
#include "TChain.h"
#include "TTree.h"
#include "TParameter.h"
#include "TFile.h"
#include <iostream>

Double_t elow = 0.13;
Double_t ehigh = 100.;

void makeShort(TString year, TString month, TString day){

    TChain* c = new TChain("clusters_tree");
    TChain* d = new TChain("finfo");

    int nFiles = 0;
    double efact = 6.04E-3;

    TString infolder = "/data/directory1/";
    TString contains = year + month + day;

    TString outfolder = "/data/directory1/";
    TFile* fout = new 
TFile(outfolder+"/short_test"+contains+".root","RECREATE");

    TSystemDirectory dir(infolder, infolder);
    TList *files = dir.GetListOfFiles();
    if (files){
        TSystemFile *file;
        TString fname;
        TIter next(files);
        while ((file=(TSystemFile*)next())) {
            fname = file->GetName();
            if (file->IsDirectory() && fname.Contains(contains)) {
                nFiles += c->Add(infolder+fname+"/*.root");
                          d->Add(infolder+fname+"/*.root");
            }
        }
        cout << "Found " << nFiles << " files" << endl;
    }

    TTree* details = new TTree("details","details");
    details->Branch("nFiles",&nFiles);
    details->Branch("conversion",&efact);

    TTree* t = c->CloneTree(0);
    TParameter<double>* q = NULL;
    c->SetBranchAddress("charge_total",&q);

    Int_t nentries = c->GetEntries();

    for(Int_t i=0; i<nentries; i++){

        if(i%100000==0)
            std::cout << "Processing cluster " << i << " of " << nentries << std::endl;

        c->GetEntry(i);
        Double_t e = q->GetVal()*efact;

        if(e>elow && e<ehigh)
            t->Fill();
}

    TTree* f = d->CloneTree();

    t->Write();
    f->Write();
    details->Write();

    fout->Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using [`hadd`](https://root.cern.ch/root/html/tutorials/io/hadd.C.html).  A default ROOT build should already have the binary.

That said, I see you are essentially filling a new tree.  The way to do is to create a `TChain`, and merge to write back (as done by `hadd`).  The `clusters_Tree; 61` that you see, are not exactly copies.  These are known as cycles, and are more like versions.  I'm guessing you have 61 files (maybe 60)? They are probably because you use `TTree::CloneTree(0)` instead of `TChain::Merge(..)`.